# Is there any way to view dpm() data other than printing it on page?

Tags: debugging

I have an issue with dpm() in that it never seems to return data (and before anyone asks:

- Yes devel is installed
- Yes I am logged in as admin
- Yes print $messages is set
- Yes the permissions are correctly set
- No the data set is not empty ( dpm($node) and dpm($content) return an empty field)
- Yes it did work previously / on ocassion

it does return a message field, but it is just empty).

Is there any other way to view dpm() data, like using Drush or something? I know I should really 'fix the dpm issue' but I have asked around and there does not seem to be an answer.

Comment: Maybe your data is empty - try `dpm('foo bar');`...does that still produce a blank message?

Comment: The data is not empty. dpm($node) and dpm($content) both return an empty field.

Comment: Very strange. And this is on every Drupal site on the same machine? Or just this one site?

Comment: I only have on Drupal site on a VPS. Looks like it was resolved somewhere between fixing drush and a file descriptor limit issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you say you are logged in as admin but even so just check the permission "Access developer information" is checked for the admin role just in case that makes a difference.

I've also heard of dpm not working as a result of modules not being uninstalled before they are deleted. Maybe try [this module](https://drupal.org/project/clean_missing_modules) to see if that helps.

Another option would be to see if kpr() works instead.

Comment: Yes the permissions are set - can we move past the quick-n-easy checks?

drush clean-modules returns 'nothing to disable'

kpr() seems to work (using normal krumo reporting section)

Comment: Yes, I did also make some other suggestions.

Comment: I'm not too sure what did it, but both kpr() and dpm() are now working.

I did, however, have some issues with drush executing (and fork: Resource temporarily unavailable errors with SSH) that I had to fix. Perhaps it was something between the drush issue and the file descriptor limit issue that fixed it

Comment: Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question "Is there any way to view `dpm()` data other than printing it on page?": I've found [Object log](https://drupal.org/project/object_log) useful for times when I can't get a `dpm()` printout (for example, when testing web services).

> The Object Log module allows developers to store objects, arrays and other variables to a log table so that they may be inspected later. Multiple stored variables may be displayed side-by-side in the Object log under admin/reports.
>
> The usage is similar to Devel module's dpm() or kprint_r() functions, but is particularly suited for debugging server-to-server requests, such as cron runs and web services, or for requests from anonymous and other unprivileged users.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to display the output of dpm() and other debug helpers like kint from drush also. Just make sure to add --debug to your drush command.

So instead of `drush migrate-import mymigration`

, use `drush migrate-import mymigration`**`--debug`**

Your debug code does of course need to be run during the drush command, so make sure you pick a command that uses you code. I used this to work with the migrate_spreadsheet module, so running a migration was enough for me to get my feedback.